# How can I get back my reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

Somehow I loose 5 points of reputation by the action of *Deleted user* and they weren't restored.

Could you give me an advise what can I do in such situation? Maybe there is some *support* that could resolve my problems?

I didn't want to make so much noise about this but it is better to know how it works if it happens again.

Comment: This happens to many of us every couple months or so. Users get removed, and the rep points they gave us go away with them. Two days ago, Tᴚoɯɐuo saw [30 points evaporate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/999cZ.png) when a user was removed. One week before that, [I lost 20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbBzt.png).

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, 5 points is minuscule.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Andrew I'm sure if Gamilato had 60K+ reputation it would be less noticeable :) As it stands, that 5 points would have gotten them to 300 rep which is a new privilege (create tags). Regardless I think the question was more about understanding the system than worrying about the reputation from one vote.

Comment: It was not about points but about clarifying how it works, ColleenV was right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next to the event in your [reputation list](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/81713/gamilato?tab=reputation) there is a [learn more](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed) link that says:

> This message means that a user who voted for one of your posts had their account deleted (either by request or due to violating the network's terms of service). As a result, all of their votes were removed, and the reputation you gained or lost from them was undone. (...)
>
> This removal occurs whenever a user is deleted, **unless that user had a very high reputation score**. Because high-reputation users have usually cast a great many votes, removing all of them could be that much more disruptive to other users.

There is also an FAQ post on Meta discussing it: [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/273494)

The user that was deleted did not have a high reputation score, so the reputation from the one up-vote they cast on your question is gone. If they had down-voted your question you would have seen some reputation added back to your account when the user was removed.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. I just understood it first in a wrong way.